# How can I send a command to windows from an android phone to execute a simple batch script or a VBScript?

Tags: android, windows-7, vbscript, ssh, popup

Hope this isn't a complicated question, but the idea is that I want to send a command to windows laptop via android's terminal to display a popup message.

I was trying to set up a ssh server on it but that's too much for something so simple yet I don't know how to do it...

so if anyone knows how could I accomplish this without too much of a hassle, I'd love to hear what do I need to do or/and read up!

Comment: I think you should go with ssh. It is a good and secure solution that runs on both platforms. Here is a link I found for inspiration: http://4sysops.com/archives/three-ways-to-run-remote-windows-commands/